# Execute code from string in net core runtime?

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn, dynamically-generated

For example we have such a class:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public int x = 0;
        public int y = 1;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Program program = new Program();
           
            program.RunScript(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        public void RunScript(string script)
        {
            //....
        }
        public void CallMethod1()
        {

        }

        public void CallMethod2()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And in the console I want to enter an expression for execution, in the language C#:

```
"if(x > y){CallMethod1();}else{CallMethod2();}"
```

how can this expression be executed? I've seen examples with Roslyn https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/may/net-core-cross-platform-code-generation-with-roslyn-and-net-core
but they call static functions or functions from the new namespace, but I need to call a function that is already in the current namespace

Comment: it´s not that simple to "just call a method". You need to specifiy the instance (if the method is non-static) and the args of course as well as the type where the method is defined. What is x and y? Please be more specific on what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: on the client side there is a file in which the logic of working with elements is written,  need to call methods depending on what will happen as a result of logical operations.
x and y are conditionally local variables for working with them, instead of int it can be a string, methods are bound to the current object.

methods can change the value of local variables.
eg
public void CallMethod1 ()
{
x + = y + x;
 }

Comment: I would suggest that you **don't** want your application to be able to execute arbitrary user-provided code, since that's an absolutely gaping security hole.

Comment: just want it, this application is not for the general public, it works strictly on a computer closed from the outside world under the control of a specialist.

the operator needs to be given full control over the process without having to recompile the program every time

Comment: the main methods will be embedded in the program itself, but the manipulation of methods should be dynamic

Comment: @Magals It sounds like you want a user interface.

Comment: @DanielMann not really. the fact is that there will be about 500 such private computers. each has its own setting over actions. the first computer will have, for example: if (x> y), the second if (x <y), and so on, with more complex constructions, but the software is the same

Comment: found a solution that will help solve the problem.
https://github.com/davideicardi/DynamicExpresso